# Using V-bind to set CSS vars in Vue 3 Composition issue

Tags: css, vuejs3, el-plus

I apologize ahead of time if the answer is obvious, I'll admit I have never truly understood the bones of CSS vars!

**What I am trying to do:** Use Vue 3 composition APIs v-bind to override a CSS value of the element plus (don't think the package is relevant but just in case) dynamically using a var.

**Here is where I am stumped:**

This works:

```
<template>
    <span class="test">
        TEST
    </span>
    <el-button type="primary">Primary</el-button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const color = 'green';
</script>

<style>
:root {
    --el-color-primary: green;
}

.test {
    background: v-bind(color);
}
</style>
```

In the code above both root primary colors are overridden and the .text class uses the `color` value as expected.

However, if I try:

```
<style>
:root {
    --el-color-primary: v-bind(color);
}
</style>
```

It is being "Seen" as not defaulting to its original color (blue).
however, It doesn't use the expected value (green) it just uses no color.

Very grateful for anyone who can see what I can't!

**EDIT:** To reiterate the first block of code I posted works! My question is trying to explore why the second code block  `--el-color-primary: v-bind(color);`  does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change css variables with `v-bind()` - set this variable to some wrapper in the component.
If you want to change css variables in `:root` - use `style.setProperty()`.

I gave an example of three cases: [**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: Kind sir! Adding `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--el-color-primary', props.userSettings.primary_color);` was all I needed.

Comment: With this way, I encounter a `document  is not defined` error in vue3 with composition API

Comment: @DamienC Where do you refer to `document`?

Comment: In my (ts) script in .vue file

Comment: @DamienC I can't help you without a code example

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to bind css in the span element by using variable

```
<span class="test">
        TEST
    </span>
```

i think you can do this

```
var color = 'green';
 <span :style="{ color: color }">   TEST</span>
```

and advice to use composition api

or try this

```
<el-button class="primary" type="primary">Primary</el-button>


<script>
import {ref} from "vue";
export default {
setup(){

  const color = ref('green');
 
  return{
      color,
}
}
}
</script>
<style scoped>

.primary {

    color: v-bind(color);
}

</style>
```

Comment: I am using the composition API. `Script setup` is just syntactic sugar.

The reason I am not placing it inline is that I need this override to occur in every occurrence that would use the `--el-color-primary` var

Comment: i somehow explore it but it won't work with me too